# CSS Conditional Formatting with a colour range

Tags: html, css, conditional-formatting

I am looking to create a basic chart using divs and spans and want to apply conditional formatting to each column in the chart depending on the value setting its height. The trick which I haven't been able to crack is that I want to have it function a bit like Excel conditional formatting in the example here:

[image]

Where the colours are in a range (light to dark).
Is there a simple way of doing this? I can see how I could apply static values to static colours but was hoping I could do something with colour ranges like this excel example.

So, the below screenshot shows a column chart where each column has a different shade of orange determined by the value of the column:

[image]

The closer to 25 the column is, the darker the colour.. Like-wise, the lower the value, the lighter the shade of orange is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your goal is to color a bar somewhere between two colors depending on a value. If that's the case, you can use css animations to simulate the color gradient.

The idea is this:

- Set up an animation setting the background to be one of two colors. This effectively calculates a gradient between the two colors. You do this with `@keyframes` and `animation`.
- Pause the animation, since we don't want it to actually play. This is done with `animation-play-state`.
- Select a specific frame in the animation to get the correct in-between color. This can be done with a negative `animation-delay`.

```css
.bars {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.bar {
  animation: color-gradient 25s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  width: 3em;
}

@keyframes color-gradient {
  from { background: red; }
  to   { background: blue; }
}
```

```html
<div class="bars">
  <div class="bar" style="height: 5em; animation-delay: -5s;"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 10em; animation-delay: -10s;"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 15em; animation-delay: -15s;"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 20em; animation-delay: -20s;"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="height: 25em; animation-delay: -25s;"></div>
</div>
```

The granularity can be adjusted by making the animation duration longer than 25 seconds if need be.

Comment: Thanks for this...  I will give it a go shortly! Only thing is that I currently have an animation on the bars which quickly expands them on load (kinda looks neat).  Would adding this to the same div element prevent that from working (i.e. as we are now pausing the animation?!)

Comment: The documentation suggests you can pause some animations and play others: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Comment: This done the trick perfectly for me...! Thank you! I have also learned about multiple animations in a single element as well now so thanks also for that! :)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to provide two options and maybe you can provide some more details based on these on exactly what you need.

This first one may not be what you want as it sets a specific gradient based on a specific height. Only going to provide a Codepen for this one. https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/yLMNPPM?editors=1100

This next one is more of what I think you want. If you know the max height of the bar graph you can use that to set the gradient breaks on your `linear-gradient`.

UPDATED:
HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="first" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="second" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="third" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="fourth" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="fifth" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.bar {
  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    $height: 20px * $i;
    $light: 75% + $i * -5;
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50%;
      left: 20% + ($i * 10%);
      width: 20px;
      height: $height;
      font-size: 25px;
      transform: translate(-80%, 0);
      background: hsl(35, 100%, $light);
    }
  }
}
```

Updated Codepen: https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/jOBPopj?editors=1100

ADDING a JS Option:

```js
let inputNum = document.getElementById("number");
let button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
let border = document.getElementById("border");
let dropDown = document.getElementById("cars");
function color() {
  if (inputNum.value > 0) {
    let bar = document.createElement("div");
    bar.classList.add("bar");
    border.appendChild(bar);
    let bars = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");

    let carName = document.createElement("p");
    carName.classList.add("carType");
    carName.textContent = cars.options[cars.selectedIndex].text;
    border.appendChild(carName);
    let names = document.getElementsByClassName("carType");

    let height = inputNum.value * 26;
    for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
      names[names.length - 1].style.top = "275px";
      names[names.length - 1].style.left = -5 + i * 30 + "px";
      bars[bars.length - 1].style.height = height + "px";
      bars[bars.length - 1].style.backgroundColor =
        "hsl(35, 100%," + (75 - height / 5.2) + "%)";
      bars[bars.length - 1].style.left = 10 + i * 30 + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
#border {
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border-left: 2px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
#numberContainer {
  position: relative;
  left: -5%;
}
.num {
  line-height: 10px;
}
.num:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px lightgrey solid;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20px;
}
#button1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}
.car {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.carType {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -85px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="border">
    <div id="numberContainer">
      <p class="num">10</p>
      <p class="num">9</p>
      <p class="num">8</p>
      <p class="num">7</p>
      <p class="num">6</p>
      <p class="num">5</p>
      <p class="num">4</p>
      <p class="num">3</p>
      <p class="num">2</p>
      <p class="num">1</p>
      <p class="num">0</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="number"/>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="color()" id="button1">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answers...! I understand my question may not have been too clear so have updated with a bit more detail of what I am after... I hope that helps! I was in a bit of a rush to get the original question up so hope this edit helps makes my request a bit more clear? Many thanks again!

Comment: The second example looks pretty close... However, instead of the column showing the full  gradient, I would be after the whole column showing just the colour that is at the top of the column gradient... I hope that makes sense...?

Comment: I updated the code. HSL is great for this as you can change the lightness based on a value thus rendering a range of color. In this case it goes from 50% to 75%. based on the number of bars I have.

Comment: You can change it to -10 to give a darker change in color or to whatever suits your needs. The same can be applied to hue and saturation if you really want to get crazy.

Comment: Thanks again for the update! This looks really good. I will see if I can integrate this solution. My first thought however is that the number of columns is hard coded in the SCSS - however I have dynamic numbers of columns depending on user input. I would need to see if I can integrate this idea into a more dynamic solution. Appreciate the help again though, thanks!

Comment: Since you want it to be dynamic you may want js. I added a js snippet version that takes user input and changes color based on how many cars you select. Maybe it will be better for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the further update... I had just finished applying the suggestion by Auroratide above and got it all working perfect now. I wish I could mark a couple of answers as Accepted answers as there are some really good suggestions here. Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score 0):

[edit] This answer only colors the bars from left to right, having the lightest color to the left.

I would let the container have a white background and the bars to be black, and then add a gradient over everything, with help of a pseudo-element that have set `mixed-blend-mode: lighten` to only colorize the black bars.

As a bonus, I added another pseudo-element with a repeating linear gradient consisting of a really light grey to create the horizontal lines. I then added `mixed-blend-mode: darken` to this element to make them appear "under" the bars.

I also randomized the height of the bars, by randomizing a CSS property for each bar.

This solution scales, so it doesn't matter how many bars you got, you still get a gradient over all the of bars without having to change the CSS code.

```js
let bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');

function randomize(max, min) {
  min = min || 0;
  
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

for (const bar of bars) {
  bar.style.setProperty('--bar-height', `${randomize(10, 2)}rem`);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 4.5rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 1rem;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.container::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fbe5d6, #843c0c);
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.container::after {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to top, #f4f1f1, #f4f1f1 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 1rem);
  z-index: 10;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

.bar {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: var(--bar-height);
  background-color: #000;
}

.bar + .bar {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a go. Looking at the result of your snippet however, it doesn't look like the shade of colour is dependant on the value (height) of the bar - rather it gets darker each bar from left to right, regardless of the height...??

Comment: Oh, that's what I get from sloppy reading. Yeah, I thought it was left to right. :D Justin's answer is spot on, using HSL values.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! I have tried Justin's example but need to figure out how I can make the number of columns in the SCSS dynamic as different screens have different numbers of columns. I an very much new to SCSS so will have to dig into that. Otherwise, yeah, it looks really good! Cheers again!

Comment: @CJH You don't really need SCSS, but instead reuse my solution by only updating a CSS variable through javascript. If you're interested, I can scribble something down real quick.

Comment: Ahhh I see, yes, if you were able to would be greatly appreciated! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of my and Justin's answers, but for vanilla CSS.

This answer is using HSL and CSS variables to set the color and the height.

### Randomized values

```js
let bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');

function randomize(max, min) {
  min = min || 0;
  
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

for (const bar of bars) {
  let maxValue = 25;
  let randomValue = randomize(maxValue, 2);
  let height = randomValue/2;
  
  let hue = '24deg';
  let saturation = '82%';
  let maxHue = 90;
  let minHue = 30;
  let hueRange = maxHue - minHue;
  let lightness = `${maxHue - hueRange * (randomValue/maxValue)}%`;
  
  bar.style.setProperty('--bar-height', `${height}rem`);
  bar.style.setProperty('--color-background-bar', `hsl(${hue}, ${saturation}, ${lightness})`);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 4.5rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0px 1rem;
  
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to top, #eee, #eee 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 1rem);
}

.bar {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: var(--bar-height);
  background-color: var(--color-background-bar);
}

.bar + .bar {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

### Increasing values

Static values ranging from 5 to 25, as seen in the OP's pic.

```js
let bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');

bars.forEach((bar, index) => {
  let maxValue = 25;
  let customValue = 5 + index * 5;
  let height = customValue/2;
  
  let hue = '24deg';
  let saturation = '82%';
  let maxHue = 90;
  let minHue = 30;
  let hueRange = maxHue - minHue;
  let lightness = `${maxHue - hueRange * (customValue/maxValue)}%`;

  bar.style.setProperty('--bar-height', `${height}rem`);
  bar.style.setProperty('--color-background-bar', `hsl(${hue}, ${saturation}, ${lightness})`);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 4.5rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0px 1rem;
  
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to top, #eee, #eee 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 1rem);
}

.bar {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: var(--bar-height);
  background-color: var(--color-background-bar);
}

.bar + .bar {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Rickard....! Just as you posted I had accepted the top response (Auroratide) as the accepted answer... A different spin on it but an interesting one. Wish I could mark a couple of these as correct answers!